# Creating instance for ADT with Contravariant, Divisible, and Decidable

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create an instance for [`Grouping1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.2.1/docs/Data-Discrimination-Grouping.html)

```
import Data.Discrimination
import Data.Discrimination.Grouping (hashing)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.Exts (toList, fromList)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as HashMap

data JSONPrimitive = JString | JNumber | JBool | JNull deriving (Show, Eq, Generic, Hashable, Grouping)
data JSONTypeF a =
    JObject (HashMap.HashMap Text a)
  | JArray (Maybe a)
  | JInvalidArray (Vector a)
  | JPrimitive JSONPrimitive
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Generic)

instance (Grouping a, Eq a, Hashable a) => Grouping1 (HashMap.HashMap a) where
  grouping1 g = contramap toList $ grouping1 (divide id grouping g)
instance Grouping1 Vector where
  grouping1 g = contramap toList (grouping1 g)
instance Grouping Text where
  grouping = hashing
```

However, I'm not sure how to define the instance `Grouping1 JSONTypeF` for the `JSONTypeF` ADT.

```
instance Grouping1 JSONTypeF where
  grouping1 g = contramap fun _
    where
      fun (JObject map) = undefined
      fun (JArray ary) = undefined
      fun (JInvalidArray ary) = undefined
      fun (JPrimitive primitive) = undefined
```

Comment: Any reason to not just use the `Generic` derived instance?

Comment: Yeah, no `Generic1` for `HashMap`. Currently building something on top of https://github.com/ekmett/discrimination/blob/master/src/Data/Discrimination/Grouping.hs#L79

Comment: `Generic1 (HashMap a)` shouldn't be needed, just `Grouping1 (HashMap.HashMap a)`.

Comment: It does need a `Generic1` for the full `JSONTypeF`, which apparently requires a `Generic` of the HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it the hard way, without any of the instance, although some nesting of `choose` might have made it possible.

```
instance Grouping1 JSONTypeF where
  grouping1 g = Group $ \k -> do
    kb <- flip getGroup
    kc <- flip getGroup
    kd <- flip getGroup
    ke <- flip getGroup
    pure (\obj ->
            case obj of
              (JObject map) -> kb map
              (JArray ary) -> kc ary
              (JInvalidArray ary) -> kd ary
              (JPrimitive primitive) -> ke primitive
            ) k
```